# Are there other functions of sets $f$ such that they have this property?

Tags: functions, logarithms

$f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$

This function is similar to the $\log_c$ function in that application of it onto a multiplication is equivalent to the summation of its applications.

$\log_c(ab) = \log_c(a) + \log_c(b)$

I'd originally asked a question about how many functions on the reals had this property, leading to the conclusion that all such functions are $\log_c$ for some $c \in \mathbb R^+$ or $\lim c \to 0 \text{ or } \infty$.

I have found one such function, the constant function: $$f(X) = C$$

I suspected that there were no other such function on sets in general.

My reasoning came from that $A, B$ are trivially strict subsets of larger sets $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$. As such, we can safely say that $f(A \cap B) = f(A \cap \mathcal A \cap B \cap \mathcal B)$. By the property of $f$,

\begin{align}
f(A \cap B) &= f(A \cap \mathcal A \cap B \cap \mathcal B) \\
            &= f(A) \cup f(\mathcal A) \cup f(B) \cup f(\mathcal B) \\
            &= f(A) \cup f(B)
\end{align}

This means that all strict supersets of $A, B$ must map to $\varnothing, f(A), \text{or } f(B)$. We can then continue to pick strict supersets that contain $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ and show that they also map to $\varnothing, f(A), \text{or } f(B)$. By infinite descent, there are at most three values this function can take.

That's as far as I can get.

Given that Henning Makholm has found a function $f$ that had this property, it's unlikely that following my reasoning above would have been fruitful.

Are there others?

---

If we consider bags instead?

A bag is a function $b : X \to \mathbb N$ for which most set operations are defined. It can be thought of as a set that allows duplicates.

$x \in b \iff b(x) > 0$

$\left(b_1 \cup b_2\right)(x) = \max\left(b_1(x), b_2(x)\right)$

$\left(b_1 \cap b_2\right)(x) = \min\left(b_1(x), b_2(x)\right)$

$\left(b_1 - b_2\right)(x) = \max\left(b_1(x) - b_2(x), 0\right)$

Are there any functions with this property over the bags other than the constant function?

$$
f(x) = c
$$

Comment: I don't see how you're getting "all strict supersets of $A,B$ must map to $\varnothing$, $f(A)$, or $f(B)$". The best I can conclude from what comes before is that $f(\mathcal A)$ and $f(\mathcal B)$ must be subsets of $f(A)\cup f(B)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A potential misstep. I'll reevaluate my logic shortly. Unfortunately, I have to leave for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed set $K$,
$$ f(X) = K\setminus X $$
will work.

You can compose this with any function on $\mathcal P(K)$ that preserves unions, to get things like
$$ f(X) = \{ x+n \mid x\in \mathbb R\setminus X, n\in \mathbb Z \} \cup \{42\} $$

Comment: Alright, can we show that this is the only such function?

Comment: @Axoren: Since $f(\emptyset) = f(\emptyset \cap X) = f(\emptyset) \cup f(X)$ for any $X$, it must be the case that $f(X) \subseteq f(\emptyset)$ for all $X$.  And if we denote by $U$ the universe, then $f(X) = f(X \cap U) = f(X) \cup f(U)$ for any $X$, and we can similarly conclude that $f(U) \subseteq f(X)$ for all $X$.

Comment: (That's not a complete demonstration, just a start.  Still thinking about it.)

Comment: I will add that this can't be the characterization of all such $f$, since we can simply identify some bijection $g: K \cup M \to L$ for some $L$, and then any $h(X) = g(f(X))$ also works.  But perhaps you can show that it covers all the cases up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Think in the De Moivre law:
$$(A\cap B)^c = A^c\cup B^c.$$
($A^c = U\setminus A$ for some fixed universe $U$).
More general: if  $h:U\longrightarrow U$ is a bijection,
$$(h(A\cap B))^c = (h(A)\cap h(B)))^c = h(A)^c\cup h(B)^c.$$